# Difference between SlidingPaneLayout and NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I really don't know what is the difference between these two approaches of creating navigation menu. So I read that both can be used as a container for two fragments (main fragment, detail fragment). So can you help me to understand which approach is better and why? I can't find out relevant information.

thank you.

Answer (score 8):

The session was "Android Design for UI Developers" by Roman Nurik and Nick Butcher:
https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/326204977

Pretty much what CommonsWare said, essentially, Navigation Drawer is for chrome and top level navigation, so it overlays app content. SlidingPaneLayout is for content navigation, thus it doesn't overlay content.

EDIT:
The video is still available here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl3-lzlzOJI

Answer (score 7):

> So can you help me to understand which approach is better and why? I can't find out relevant information.

This was covered in a Google I|O 2013 presentation, though I forget which one.

`SlidingPaneLayout` is for content, such as the master-detail pattern. You might use it in place of two layouts for master-detail structures for smaller and larger screens.

`DrawerLayout` is for navigation. You might use it in place of the dashboard pattern, or using action bar items for navigation, if you have a fair bit of navigation in your app.

Comment: isn't the master-detail pattern also showing navigation between pages?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: You are welcome to define those nouns and verbs however you like. Google does not consider the master-detail to be navigation.

Comment: I've watched the video yesterday. I think the difference for them is that the master-detail pattern just shows a static navigation drawer, one that doesn't move at all. Am I correct ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: No, because they consider the `SlidingPaneLayout` to be a "responsive design" way of implementing the master-detail pattern.

Comment: i don't understand . what does it mean for the end user perspective? what other differences other than what i've written are there?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: You'll have to ask Google. They are the ones who are providing the advice; I and yuntao are merely pointing you to their statements. For example, you might read [the JavaDocs for `SlidingPaneLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html), which has "SlidingPaneLayout is distinct from a navigation drawer as described in the design guide and should not be used in the same scenarios" and elaborations on the same.

Comment: Sorry. still can't find a lot of differences. SlidingPaneLayout is able to show itself depending on the size of the screen and cannot be toggled by the user, while the navigation drawer stays the way it is (toggled by the user). both are used to navigate between pages. i think they could be merged into a single view. I guess I will need some more experience with them to find out the answer, but from my current perspective, I don't see much difference.