# Android, slidingpanelayout vs navigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm about to use one of them and yet i'm very confused.

I don't know the difference. to me, both look the same.

I've passed through this [Difference between SlidingPaneLayout and NavigationDrawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801611/difference-between-slidingpanelayout-and-navigationdrawer)

may anyone tell the difference between them??

Comment: gmail tablet uses slidingpanelayout for primary navigation (Sept 2015)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is what the official Navigation Drawer ([`DrawerLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)) looks like:

[image]

And this is what the [`SlidingPaneLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) looks like:

[image]

Both serve different purposes. The `DrawerLayout` serves as a menu, to put it simple. The `SlidingPaneLayout` on the other hand is a what you would use, if the content of both your screens would interact with each other. Or to as the documentation puts it:

> The `SlidingPaneLayout` should be thought of only as a way to allow a
>   two-pane layout normally used on larger screens to adapt to smaller
>   screens in a natural way

Comment: What does the new Youtube app use? It slides more easily then tha Nav draw but it doesnt push the content out of the way like SlidingPaneLayout. Im guessing they broke they're own guidelines, again.

Comment: @Karl the youtube app uses the DrawerLayout. They modified it a little bit so it could push away the video preview in the righthand bottom corner, but other than that it's just a DrawerLayout with a semi-transparent background.

Comment: I don't think it is. It slides a lot easier than DrawerLayout. It slides from anywhere in the screen, DrawerLayout only from 20dp of the edge. Im looking to get the same slide like in youtube app but only managed an ugly hack of DL so far...

Comment: Left pane ABOVE right pane -> it's a Navigation Drawer. Left pane BELOW right pane -> it's a Sliding Pane Layout. Basically, Google puts the main content on the lower layer (pane that's below). The lower pane has more functionality, as well, such as swipe to archive. (And in fact, the navigation drawer in the Youtube app cannot be open by swiping from any place on the screen, as you are saying, but only from the edge. As of right now at least.)

Comment: Furthermore, if you use fragments for the two "panes" and you have menu items specified, that appear in the ActionBar, the behaviour varies between the two approaches. With the NavigationDrawer the ActionBar only shows items from the currently shown "pane". With the SlidingPaneLayout all menu items (from both fragments) will be shown in the ActionBar, no matter which "pane" is active.

Comment: @Stan I guess you are wrong about the ActionBar menu items. With `SlidingPaneLayout` you can change the ActionBar menu items depending wich pane is active. To exemplify take a look at this tutorial http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial.html or even at the Hangouts app.